# Attributed text with two text alignments

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Does anyone know how to achieve two different text alignments in one string?

This is what I want the textView to show:

```
label                                                                         value
```

My code:

```
let txtView = cell.viewWithTag(77) as! UITextView

let leftStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
leftStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
let rightStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
rightStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

let attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "label", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: leftStyle])
attText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: " "))
attText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "value", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: rightStyle]))

txtView.attributedText = attText
```

What I get instead:

```
label value
```

Comment: take one UIVIew and set both UILabel, one is align at left and another to right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `NSMutableParagraphStyle` with `NSTextTab`:

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.tabStops = [
    NSTextTab(textAlignment: .Right, location: 100, options: [:]),
]

let str = "Label\tValue\n"
    + "foo\tbar\n"

let attributed = NSAttributedString(
    string: str,
    attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph]
)

let view = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))
view.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 10

view.attributedText = attributed
```

[image: screenshot]

Of course, this aligns to "tabstop", but not to the edge of `UITextView`. When you modify the size of the view, you have to also modify the `location` of `NSTextTab`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! :)

Comment: @rintaro - Why did you do location: 100? What does 100 mean?

Comment: @SamB 100 is `view.textContainer.size.width - view.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding * 2`. That means the right edge of the text area.

Answer (score -1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let cell = Placestableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath);

        //first text
        let attributestitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:
            UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!,
                          NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black] as [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]

        //second text
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\t"+String(places[indexPath.row].distance!)+" miles", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 8.0)!,NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])


        let myParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        myParagraphStyle.alignment = .right
        myParagraphStyle.tabStops = [
            NSTextTab(textAlignment: .right, location: 300, options: [:]),
        ]

        let attributedStringtitle  = NSMutableAttributedString(string: places[indexPath.row].title!, attributes: attributestitle)
        //adding the right alignment to the second text alone
        attributedString.addAttributes([.paragraphStyle: myParagraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

        //combining two texts with different alignments.
        let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()
        combination.append(attributedStringtitle)
        combination.append(attributedString)
        cell.textLabel?.attributedText = combination
        return cell;
    }
```