# NSAttributedString with two different text alignments

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

I'm trying to display some text in a UILabel using attributedText, with 2 different text alignments. I'm fetching the values from Firebase & they are key and value types. For some reason I can't get the title to be aligned left and the subtitle aligned right. Any help is appreciated.

```
 private func descriptionAttributedText() -> NSAttributedString {
    let title = "some title on the left side of the screen"
    let subtitle = "subtitle on the right side"

    let rightParagraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    rightParagraph.alignment = .right

    let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: titleAttributes)

    let subtitleAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: rightParagraph]
    let subtitleString = NSAttributedString(string: subtitle, attributes: subtitleAttributes)

    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.setParagraphStyle(.default)
    paragraph.lineSpacing = 2

    let range = NSMakeRange(0, titleString.string.count)
    titleString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: range)

    titleString.append(subtitleString)


    return titleString
}
```

The result I'm getting is of type "Titlesubtitle"

I have looked here, [Attributed text with two text alignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029576/attributed-text-with-two-text-alignments), but it doesn't help me much.

I'm trying to get the same effect as on the App Store, but instead of

Seller ..................... Facebook Inc. , I'm getting

SellerFacebook Inc.

[image: img_5752]

Comment: why you say they are not aligned? might you post what you get?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: I see, then you cannot solve the problem in that way (`NSAttributedString`). In the picture, there is probably a `UITableView` (might be also a custom `UIVIew`) with a `UITableViewCell` (talking about the first one) having 2 different `UILabel`.

Comment: This looks like standard *Right Detail* styled cells

Comment: Its best to make them separate UILabels

Comment: This clearly seems to be two `UILabel`. It's easier. That's what I would STRONGLY suggest. But you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617365/ios-multiple-right-and-left-align-on-same-line if you really want to use one single label, but that's overkill, and make this more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using the right detail styled cells as @vadian adivsed.

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")
```

Thanks !